# How to declare variable .get_prediction() in OLS statsmodel for panel regression

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Here's my code

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
df = pd.read_csv("df_panel.csv", header=0)
pooled_olsr_model = sm.OLS(df['y_variable'], df['x_variable'])
pooled_olsr_model_results = pooled_olsr_model.fit()
train = df[df['percentage']<75]
```

then

```
pooled_olsr_model_results.get_prediction(train)
```

And output

```
ValueError: shapes (3289,4) and (1,) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Comment: You are fitting the model using just one exogenous/independent variable (`x_variable`), but are passing a 4-column dataframe to the `.get_prediction()` method. You should be passing the same number of columns there as when fitting the model. So, if just one variable, then use `.get_prediction(train['x_variable'])`.

Comment: It works, but not resulted numbers @AlexK

Comment: What are you trying to do, get predicted values? Use `pooled_olsr_model_results.predict(train['x_variable'])`.